# OAuth2.0 Я получаю новый access_token с помощью refresh_token и при повторном запросе с этим новым access_token я получаю ошибку access_denied

Tags: java, spring, авторизация

После использования refresh_token я получил новый access_token и применил его, как обычно, указав его как Bearer, но я получаю ошибку с моим новым access_token. Везде нахожу только то, как получить новые токены с помощью refresh_token, но ничего об обращении к эндпойнтам с новым access_token.

Алгоритм:

1. указываю `grant_type:password, login:***, password:***` в body (или выбрав в postman во вкладке Authorization тип OAuth2.0, всё равно);
2. Header:

   ```
   Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded, 
   Authorization:Basic ***;
   ```
3. Стучусь к себе на `../oauth/token`, получаю:

   ```
   "access_token": "***",
   "token_type": "bearer",
   "refresh_token": "***",
   "expires_in": 43199,
   "scope": "read write",
   "jti": "9e2baba7-4af4-4e8c-be09-c8268abff9c1
   ```
4. Ставлю access_token, как Bearer *** и всё ОК!
5. С помощью refresh_token получаю новые значения:

   ```
   body:
   grant_type:refresh_token;
   "refresh_token": "***";
   header:
   Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded, 
   Authorization:Basic ***;
   ```
6. Стучусь к себе на `../oauth/token`, см. пункт 3, приходит также всё отлично, всё на месте.
7. И ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ!!! Я беру access_token, который получился в пункте 6, закидываю его в header, как Bearer, в body естественно мне уже ничего не нужно, обращаюсь к своему эндпойнту и получаю ошибку:

[image]

В чем может быть проблема? Почему это не работает и что с ним происходит? Может быть, мне нужно добавить параметры в заголовок (область, jti, секрет и т. д.)? При логировании не увидел ничего нового в случае обращения к эндпойнту с рабочим и не рабочим access, разницы вообще нет.

Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Так, а что это у вас за `../oauth/token` и к какому серверу вы обращаетесь-то? Чей это сервер и что там за код если он ваш?

Comment: Прошу прощения, не уточнил, сервер мой, но реализация этого функционала из пакета Spring Security (package org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint), понимаю, что возможно нужно повнимательнее подебажить и изучить код, но позже нашёл на сайте Oracle вот такую статью https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/cx-unity/cx-unity-develop/docs/authentication/authenticating-oauth.htm, где сказано, поменять Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded на Content-Type:application/json и применять с новым аксес токеном, который получили с помощью рефреш токена, к сожалению, это не помогло.

Comment: Возможно именно где-то здесь проблема, какой-то из параметров указан не верно, или вовсе не указан?

Comment: Добавьте хоть spring (и java?) в метки